# How to calculate thrust from mass flowrate and velocity

Tags: airflow, thrust

How can I calculate thrust in Newton from mass flowrate and velocity?

Please  note,I have mathematical skills of 7 year old,the most complex task I can do is multiply and divide,I dont understand any equations.

Comment: :') Thank you for your candour. Start [here](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/thrsteq.html). You can do it!

Comment: I visited that site two times before I asked this question,I cant do it.I want to calculate thrust of fan,it moves 5 cubic meters of air per second with airflow velocity of 5 meters per second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the best learning happens when there is a need, and the internet can answer almost any question. Easiest way to understand physics is to use [SI derived units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_derived_unit) and always carry your units through your equation.

velocity = 5 m/s

mass flowrate = ?kg/s

volumetric flowrate = 5m^3/s

Thrust: ? Newtons = kg*m/s^2

I asked google what the [mass of a cubic meter of air](https://www.google.com/search?q=mass%20of%20cubic%20meter%20of%20air&oq=mass%20of%20cubic%20meter%20of%20air) was:

density = 1.293 kg/m^3

The density lets us convert your volumetric flow into mass flow:

(looks like googles calculator carries units now which is cool)

[5m^3/s * 1.293 kg/m^3](https://www.google.com/search?q=5m%5E3%2Fs%20*%201.293%20kg%2Fm%5E3%20%3D&oq=5m%5E3%2Fs%20*%201.293%20kg%2Fm%5E3%20%3D) = 6.465 kg/s

mass flow = 6.465 kg/s

Now we just multiply mass flow and velocity and confirm our units work out:

[6.465 kg/s * 5 m/s](https://www.google.com/search?ei=eql8WvnjOpC8jwPgv4egCQ&q=6.465%20kg%2Fs%20*%205%20m%2Fs%20%3D&oq=6.465%20kg%2Fs%20*%205%20m%2Fs%20%3D) = 32.325N

So the thrust is 32.325N or [7.27 pounds force](https://www.google.com/search?ei=O6p8WtW7GaW4jAPQ9JzADQ&q=32.325%20Newton%20in%20pound%20force&oq=32.325%20Newton%20in%20pound%20force)